# Prove the existence of a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with the following property.

Tags: set-theory

Suppose $\left \langle A_n\ :\ n\in\mathbb{N} \right \rangle$ is a sequence of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. 
Prove that there exist an infinite set of $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ [$A\ \cap\ A_n$ is infinite and $(\mathbb{N}\backslash A) \ \cap A_n$ is infinite]

I really wanted to do induction here, but I cant clear the base case $n=0$, so I was wondering if there are other ways to prove such existence.

Any help or insights is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In technical terms, you want to construct an $A\subseteq\Bbb N$ that [*splits*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum#Splitting_number_.7F.27.22.60UNIQ--postMath-0000002D-QINU.60.22.27.7F_and_reaping_number_.7F.27.22.60UNIQ--postMath-0000002E-QINU.60.22.27.7F) each $A_n$. Note that $A$ splits $A_n$ iff $\Bbb N\setminus A$ splits $A_n$, so the idea is to construct disjoint subsets of $\Bbb N$ that have infinite intersection with each $A_n$. You can do this recursively, picking one member of each subset at each stage.

Suppose that for some $n\in\Bbb N$ we’ve chosen $s_k,t_k\in A_k$ for each $k<n$ in such a way that the $n$ natural numbers $s_k$ and $t_k$ are all distinct. Let $S_n=\{s_k:k<n\}$ and $T_n=\{t_k:k<n\}$ and $F_n=S_n\cup T_n$. $F_n$ is finite, so $A_n\setminus F_n$ is infinite, and we can let

$$s_n=\min(A_n\setminus F_n)$$

and

$$t_n=\min\big(A_n\setminus(F_n\cup\{s_n\})\big)\;.$$

Clearly $s_n,t_n\notin F_n$, so the recursion hypothesis for the next step is satisfied, and the recursion goes through to yield disjoint infinite subsets $S=\{s_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ and $T=\{t_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ of $\Bbb N$, either of which will serve for $A$.

Comment: I was wondering if we should change the $< to \leq$ as I'm concerned about what happen if I chose my $n$ to be $0$ ?

Comment: @some1fromhell: There's no problem with $n=0$: $S_0=T_0=F_0=\varnothing$, so $s_0=\min A_0$, and $t_0=\min(A_0\setminus\{s_0\})$. That's why I don't need to give the recursion an explicit base case: the construction works just as well at $n=0$ as it does for $n>0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct $A$ step by step as follows:

Put the smallest element of $A_1$ into A, put the second-smallest element of $A_1$ not into $A$. Remove all elements smaller or equal to these from all sets $A_i$.

Repeat this with $A_2$. Then $A_1$ again, then $A_2$, then $A_3$. Then $A_1$ again, then $A_2$ again , then $A_3$ again, then $A_4$ and so on. This is a common "diagonal" argument, which hits every $A_i$ infinitely many times.

(there is probably a more elegant formulation, but I hope the idea is understandable)